# Load video on image click in subpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

I am working on a static portfolio website using html, css and javascript.
On the `index.html` I have a gallery with images. Each image represents a film. When clicking on an image, the user is directed to the `detail.html` page, where a certain video is supposed to be shown in an iframe along with the referring data.
However, I am struggeling to get the video loaded in the `detail.html` page when clicking on an image in the `index.html` page. It loads the page but not the video.
Here is the html code for `index.html`:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">
            <img alt="picture" src="img/portfolio/filmcity.jpg" width="100%" />
   </a>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
function myFunction() { 
  window.location = 'detail.html';
  var video = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  video.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jiu42WJ9Vdk");
}
```

And this is the html code for `detail.html`:

```
<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame" height="60%" src="">
</iframe>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is that you are asking. So you want the parent page to go from `index.html` to `detail.html` and in `detail.html` have it load the video in an iframe?

Comment: yes, exactly @imvain2 is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

For all of your links to detail.html have the URL like this: `detail.html?video_id=XXXXX`
where the XXXXX is the youtube id that you want to link to.

```
<a href="detail.html?video_id=Jiu42WJ9Vdk"> Watch video </a>
```

**Detail.HTML**

```
<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame" height="60%" src="about:blank;"></iframe>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function _get(name) {
    url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return "";
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var _youtube_id = _get("video_id");

if (_youtube_id.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/)){
  var video = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  video.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + _youtube_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate to a new page while still running a function on the old page. That's not how JavaScript works. You need to call your function on page load on the page it runs on. Maybe something like this:

**On index.html**

```
<!-- include the video ID as a URL parameter -->
<a href="detail.html?vid=Jiu42WJ9Vdk"> ... </a>
```

**On detail.html**

```
<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame" height="60%" src=""></iframe>

<script>
// get the video ID from the URL and use it in the iframe source string
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let vid = url.searchParams.get("vid");
let videoEl = document.getElementById("myFrame");
video.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vid);
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what to do next.